# How should Fancytree node keys be escaped to avoid special characters?

Tags: fancytree

I discovered that the '+' character in a custom node key is converted silently to a space character. I obviously need to escape these special characters, but I could not find documentation about which characters are not allowed in keys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no conversion, except for casting non-strings to a string.

When the `generateIds`option is used, the key is added as `id="KEY"` attribute to the generated HTML element, so the [standard restrictions apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/19166).
The key is also internally used as JavaScript hash key.

I'd recommend plain ascii keys, but '{', '.', '~', ... should be no problem as well.

As far as I know, `+` is interpreted as space by browsers, when part of a URL, so maybe you see the conversion there.

Comment: You are correct. It was a proxy layer that was not encoding the key value during a REST call. Thanks!